# i3 set costum screen layout as default

Tags: multiple-monitors, debian, i3-wm, layout

How do I set my screen layout so that I don't ever have to do it again? Here is what I have so far:

1. $ arandr
2. set the layout I want (for 3 monitors)
3. [save as] screen_orientation.sh
4. (Now what should do?)

Present situation is that if I exit i3 and re-login, then I lose the layout and I have to set it again. How do I set it indefinitely?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure this in your i3-config file.
Something like

> exec ~/screen_orientation.sh