# how to keep my i3 contain/tree layout indefinitely

Tags: multiple-monitors, debian, i3-wm

This is part two of the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125183/i3-set-costum-screen-layout-as-default).

Having set my layout, I went on to set my windows as I want them: I have a set of windows on monitor_1, a different set on monitor_2, a different set on monitor_3. Now I want to set this for ever. So that when my computer shutdown and restart, everything is how it's right now. What should I do?

I am of course already looking in the [doc](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) but not doing it for me.

Comment: It maybe a better idea to edit your previous question than to post "part two" as a separate question.

Comment: people say not to post two questions in one. Now you are saying the opposite. Confusing stuff :)

Comment: Please read carefully the part about saving layouts. After saving layout You HAVE to edit it and put proper window class inside. You can obtain them by running `xprop` command and clicking on the window, this will give You the instance name and class name. You put them in proper placeholder section in the layout file. Do this for every window in the layout.